# Use multiple child Controllers against @RequestMapping defined in Parent class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller, abstract

I have a parent class P which defines one request mapping like this:

```
public abstract class P {
 @RequestMapping(value = "/a/b/c", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String productLink(@RequestParam("abc") String json) throws Exception {
        return getProductLinks(json);
    }
}
```

and I have couple of children `Controller` classes and `ClassImpl` is one of them:

```
@Controller
public class ClassImpl extends P {
@RequestMapping(value = "/start", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String start(@RequestParam(value = "keyword", required = true) String keyword,
            @RequestParam(value = "keywordId", required = true) long keywordId) throws Exception {
     //Something
    }
}
```

If I run this app with only one child class, it works fine but it causes issues with multiple child controllers.

When I run my application, I get an error saying `"Cannot map handler ClassImpl to URL path [/a/b/c]: There is already handler [a.b.c.d.ClassImpl@a92aaa] mapped"`

```
It seems that because of multiple child classes, it is unable to find the controller for this mapping which is understood.
```

Is defining `@RequestMapping` in each class (or one separate class) the only way? I don't want to put similar code at all the places. Is there any workaround for this to keep it in parent class and keep using it?

Thanks,

Comment: I think it will not work.

Comment: Would it help if I told you that you can declare `@RequestMapping` annotations on the class level as well?

Comment: ^ I don't think so. We will end-up in the same trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use @RequestMapping in abstract classe. This annotation is for real controller, so concrete classe.

Use Abstract class as they are intented to use, ie to factorize code, not to do the work.

Here you can do something like :

```
public abstract class P {

    public String productLink(String json) throws Exception {
       return getProductLinks(json);
    }
}
```

and then

```
@Controller
public class ClassImpl extends P {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/start", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String start(@RequestParam(value = "keyword", required = true) String keyword,
        @RequestParam(value = "keywordId", required = true) long keywordId) throws     Exception {
         //Something
    }

    //here reusing the code from superclass
    @RequestMapping(value = "/a/b/c", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String productLink(@RequestParam("abc") String json) throws Exception {
        return super.getProductLinks(json);
    }
}
```

This add a bit of boilerplate code, but this is the way to do it IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

> Is defining @RequestMapping in each class (or one separate class) the only way?

The short answer is yes. Personally I think that it belongs in a separate class.

Why exactly do you want to put `productLink()` in the parent class, anyway?  It's not an abstract method and you're not overriding it, so to me it doesn't make much sense.